# How to get all of the instantiated controllers in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angularjs application, and I want to be able to get the list of all instantiated controllers in a given moment in Developer Tools console.

How can I do that?

I can't find either of these:

```
angular.controllers
angular.module('app').controllers
```

Non of these lines exist

Comment: what do you want to achieve through that?

Answer (score 2):

i think you can accomplish this by using `_invokeQueue`

```
angular.module('app')['_invokeQueue'].forEach(function(val) {
    console.log(val[2][0])
})
```